# How to run python script via nginx?

Tags: nginx

nginx is able to run php scripts to generate content for it to serve.

How can you get nginx to execute an arbitrary program, say, a python script, and have it serve up the output?

Answer (score 0):

### Full Stack Python

https://www.fullstackpython.com/nginx.html

OR:

### Nginx Python Module

The module allows using Python in nginx both at configuration stage and in runtime:
 https://github.com/arut/nginx-python-module

**Configuring nginx with the module:**

```
# static module
$ ./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx-python-module

# dynamic module
$ ./configure --add-dynamic-module=/path/to/nginx-python-module

# sync-only version (no blocking operations substitution)
$ ./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx-python-module
              --with-cc-opt=-DNGX_PYTHON_SYNC=1

# a specific Python installation can be used by exporting
# the path to python-config prior to configuring
$ export PYTHON_CONFIG=/path/to/python-config
```

Comment: There's no nginx technology called "Full Stack Python", it's the name of a website/book. Did you mean "WSGI"? That's the most popular method, but the linked page really has only an offhand mention of how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Using nginx's `fastgci_pass`.

Here is an example using `fcgiwrap` with a perl script:

https://www.howtoforge.com/serving-cgi-scripts-with-nginx-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.04-p3